# Stored procedure: Variable table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make it easier to insert new default values to existing columns from my setup. For better overview and less errors, I want to make a oneliner from a three-liner with redundant names. My first attempt at a store dprocedure for that is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDefault
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName VARCHAR(200),
    @FieldName VARCHAR(200),
    @DefaultValue VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND name = @FieldName)
        ALTER TABLE @TableName ADD @FieldName [int] CONSTRAINT CONCAT('DF_', @TableName, '_', @FieldName) DEFAULT @DefaultValue NOT NULL
    GO
END
GO
```

But it seems that `ALTER TABLE @TableName` does not work, nor does the concatenation for the constraint name.

What am I missing here?

And then, is there a possibility to make `@DefaultValue` a mixed type?

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: Agreed with @FelixPamittan

Comment: T-SQL is not well suited to parametrizing on table or column names. I don't see what this stored procedure is meant to be gaining for you over just writing the `ALTER TABLE` statement directly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Less error prone, because you could easily forget to change the column name in one of the three locations after copy & paste. Let me say it like this, the problem is a practical one, not just academic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql (don't forget to escape single quotes in query string if they are present):

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
select @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' ADD ' + @FieldName 
       + ' [int] CONSTRAINT ' + CONCAT('DF_', @TableName, '_', @FieldName) 
       + ' DEFAULT ' + @DefaultValue + ' NOT NULL'
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

Comment: You have to do the `CONCAT` in the outer SQL and put its *value* into the dynamic SQL. You cannot *name* a constraint `CONCAT('DF_'...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND name = @FieldName)
        exec('ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + 'ADD ' + @FieldName + ' [int] CONSTRAINT CONCAT(''DF_'', ' + @TableName + ','' _'', ' + @FieldName + ') DEFAULT ' + @DefaultValue + ' NOT NULL')
    GO
END
```